# Scanf with double in C returns 0.00000

Tags: c, input, double, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

double a, b;

    scanf("%lf %lf\n", &a, &b);
    printf("%lf%lf\n", a, b);
}
```

Why does it always return 0.0000 regardless of what I write?

Comment: *Always* check the return value of `scanf` family functions. Also, please provide [mcve], or you will only get useless guessing from others as a result.

Comment: What exactly is your input ? Remove the `\n` from the `scanf` format specifier.

Comment: It works for me, though you have to type something else after the two input doubles due to the `\n` in the `scanf` format string.

Comment: It works. Take a look [here](http://ideone.com/bC2KbM)